# How to match a String against string literals?

Tags: string, match, rust

I'm trying to figure out how to match a `String` in Rust.

I initially tried matching like this, but I figured out Rust cannot implicitly cast from `std::string::String` to `&str`.

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match stringthing {
        "a" => println!("0"),
        "b" => println!("1"),
        "c" => println!("2"),
    }
}
```

This has the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         "a" => println!("0"),
  |         ^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

I then tried to construct new `String` objects, as I could not find a function to cast a `String` to a `&str`.

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match stringthing {
        String::from("a") => println!("0"),
        String::from("b") => println!("1"),
        String::from("c") => println!("2"),
    }
}
```

This gave me the following error 3 times:

```
error[E0164]: `String::from` does not name a tuple variant or a tuple struct
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         String::from("a") => return 0,
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a tuple variant or struct
```

How to actually match `String`s in Rust?

Comment: `stringthing.as_str()` is probably the most straightforward of all the answers; I don't like `as_ref` because it's unnecessarily general, which can lead to bugs, and not as explicit, it isn't completely clear that `as_ref()` is going to be a `&str`, `as_str` is simple and clear.

Comment: @Zorf You are right. The answer was accepted when `as_str` did not exist yet. I changed the accepted answer but thank all people who answered this question!

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
match &stringthing[..] {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

There's also an `as_str` method as of Rust 1.7.0:

```
match stringthing.as_str() {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

Answer (score 397):

**UPDATE:**
Use `.as_str()` like this to convert the `String` to an `&str`:

```
match stringthing.as_str() {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

**Reason**
`.as_str()` is more concise and enforces stricter type checking. The trait `as_ref` is implemented for multiple types and its behaviour could be changed for type `String`, leading to unexpected results. Similarly, if the input argument changes type, the compiler will not signal a problem when that type implements the trait `as_ref`.

The docs suggest to use `as_str` as well https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html

**Old answer:**

`as_slice` is deprecated, you should now use the trait `std::convert::AsRef` instead:

```
match stringthing.as_ref() {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

Note that you also have to explicitly handle the catch-all case.

Comment: using rust 1.4.0 one can use the `trim()` function. Just using `as_ref()` doesn't match the string.

Comment: I think the match fails because of whitespace that `trim()` removes. This is nice for deferencing to match against user input.

Comment: It doesn't work. It can only match _ if I get String from read_line.

Comment: Don't know much about how rust manages different types of strings, but [it seems to work on a basic example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d3a1379484fd4a01aa1c16e6cb32d187&version=nightly).

Comment: @MaskedMan `read_line` reads a line. Lines end in `\n`. `.trim_end()` (or, more precisely, `trim_end_matches('\n')`) will remove that for you.

Comment: I'm not getting `.as_str()` at all.  It is not being allowed for a string parameter, "`xx`": "`foo( xx : &str )`".  While ... "`match xx  { "ABC" => "XYZ", ... }`", works fine.  Which is a '[borowed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) instance/parameter.   How does that work-in if the correct, or _better_, method is to use `as_str()`?

Comment: Note that `.as_str()` only exists on owned `String` and not `&str`. If you only care about matching against string contents but don't care about the concrete type, perhaps `match &mystring[..]` is more flexible/general.

Answer (score 25):

You could also do

```
match &stringthing as &str {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

See:

- [`std::string::String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref)
- [`std::ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)
- [Deref coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html)

Comment: This is effectively the same as `.as_str()` and that is way shorter.

Comment: ".as_str()" is literally 1 more character than "as &str" though? am I missing something? @amyiris

Comment: `&x as &str` is 10 characters and `x.as_str()` is 10 characters.  Same length.

Answer (score 11):

> Editor's note: This answer pertains to an version of Rust before 1.0 and does not work in Rust 1.0

You can match on a string slice.

```
match stringthing.as_slice() {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

Comment: better to use `.as_ref()` or `.as_str()`, both did not take ownership.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the String to a &str using the as_str() method, and then match on the &str value like so:

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match stringthing.as_str() {
        "a" => println!("0"),
        "b" => println!("1"),
        "c" => println!("2"),
        _ => println!("other"),
    }
}
```

Or you can bind the String value to a variable, and then match on the variable like so:

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match stringthing {
        ref x if x == "a" => println!("0"),
        ref x if x == "b" => println!("1"),
        ref x if x == "c" => println!("2"),
        _ => println!("other"),
    }
}
```

Or you can use the == operator to compare the String value with a string literal like so:

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    if stringthing == "a" {
        println!("0");
    } else if stringthing == "b" {
        println!("1");
    } else if stringthing == "c" {
        println!("2");
    } else {
        println!("other");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match &*stringthing {
        "a" => println!("0"),
        "b" => println!("1"),
        "c" => println!("2"),
        _ => println!("else")
    }
}
```

Comment: It might improve the usefulness of your answer if you explain what `&*stringthing` means and does.

Comment: `String` implements `Deref<Target = str>`. So `stringthing` is dereferencend with `*stringthing` to a `str` and `&*stringthing` gets referenced to `&str`. According with the Rust documentation is this a more idiomatic way than using `as_str()`.

Comment: This is good for whom has compulsion, `s.as_ref()` and `s.as_str()` are ugly, `&*s` is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `String` into `&str` by doing this:

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match &stringthing[..] {
        "a" => println!("0"),
        "b" => println!("1"),
        "c" => println!("2"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rust, you typically cannot use a String directly in a match statement because String is a dynamic, heap-allocated data type, and match expects values with a known and fixed set of possibilities at compile time.

However, you can use a String in a match statement by first converting it to a &str using the as_str() method or by using pattern matching with a reference to the String.

**match** expects exhaustive and known patterns: The match expression requires you to specify all possible patterns at compile time. **String literals are known at compile time**, so you can use them directly in a match. On the other hand, the content of a **String is determined at runtime** and can vary, so it cannot be directly used in a match.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers already revealed, `String` is not `str`. So basically any function that can convert to an `str` will do. When reading something from the command line, I especially found useful the [`trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim) method (get rid of the new line, and return an `str`. As marked in the comments, it does an automatic dereference during the call.

Here is the code I used:

```
let mut input: String = Default::default();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)
           .expect("Something bad happened");
match input.trim() {
    "a" => println!("0"),
    "b" => println!("1"),
    "c" => println!("2"),
    _ => println!("something else!"),
}
```

Comment: `trim()` does not "convert `String` to `str`", it operates on `&str` only. Auto-deref does the conversion, and `trim()` is an additional step you apply on top of it.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I was too happy after my 'Hello Word 2' application that I've found a new way to solve this. I'll incorporate the auto-deref part as soon as I understand it.

Answer (score -2):

Use as_str() on Strings to get string slice

```
fn main() {
    let stringthing = String::from("c");
    match stringthing.as_str() {
        String::from("a") => println!("0"),
        String::from("b") => println!("1"),
        String::from("c") => println!("2"),
    }
}
```

if your taking input from the console and want to perform match on it be sure to call trim() after as_str() to remove escape character i.e '\n' from the input. As in

```
match stringthing.as_str().trim() {...}
```

Comment: This does not work. Error: expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found associated function `String::from`. 

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021