# Using slice patterns with a slice of Strings

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to use slice patterns on a slice of `String`s. This does not work because Rust does not match the `String`s of the slice with the `&str` literal. I could not find out how to convert the slice of `String`s to a slice of `&str`s.

```rust
#![feature(slice_patterns)]

fn main() {
    // A slice of strings.
    let x = ["foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned()];
    match x {
        ["foo", y] => println!("y is {}.", y),
        _ => println!("I did not expect this."),
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://is.gd/0TyjUv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you don't have a slice of `String`s (`&[String]`), you have an *array* of `String`s (`[String; 2]`).

Let's take a look at a smaller case:

```
fn main() {
    match "foo".to_owned() {
        "foo" => println!("matched"),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

Here, we get the same error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         "foo" => println!("matched"),
  |         ^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

The fix in this case is to change the `String` into a `&str`, which is what the slice patterns understand:

```
let s = "foo".to_owned();
match s.as_str() {
    "foo" => println!("matched"),
    _ => unreachable!(),
}
```

See also:

- [How to match a String against string literals in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25383488/155423)

So, how can we expand this to your example? The straight-forward thing is to do the same thing twice:

```
fn main() {
    let x = ["foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned()];

    match [x[0].as_str(), x[1].as_str()] {
        ["foo", y] => println!("y is {}.", y),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

However, this wouldn't work for the case of a slice (`&[T]`) because we only handle two values, not an arbitrary amount. In that case, we need to make a temporary `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = ["foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned()];
    let x2: Vec<_> = x.iter().map(|x| x.as_str()).collect();

    match x2.as_slice() {
        ["foo", y] => println!("y is {}.", y),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

Note that you have to convert the `Vec` into a slice itself (`x2.as_slice()`) because slice patterns only understand slices.

Comment: Is there a difference between creating a string slice e.g. `&x[..]` and doing an explicit reborrow e.h. `&*x`?

Comment: @chad I don't *think* there is a difference, but I am not sure. That sounds like a straight-forward thing you could [ask a new question for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and get a more reliable answer for, and maybe some points. :-)

Comment: This is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860750/is-there-a-difference-between-slicing-and-an-explicit-reborrow-when-converting-s