# Is there a difference between slicing and an explicit reborrow when converting Strings to &strs?

Tags: memory, type-conversion, rust

Are the following two examples equivalent?

Example 1:

```
let x = String::new();
let y = &x[..];
```

Example 2:

```
let x = String::new();
let y = &*x;
```

Is one more efficient than the other or are they basically the same?

Comment: If appropriate for the answer, I'd also like to extend the question to `Vec<T>` and `&[T]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of [`String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) and [`Vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), they do the same thing.  In *general*, however, they aren't quite equivalent.

First, you have to understand [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html).  This trait is implemented in cases where a type is logically "wrapping" some lower-level, simpler value.  For example, all of the "smart pointer" types (`Box`, `Rc`, `Arc`) implement `Deref` to give you access to their contents.

It is also implemented for `String` and `Vec`: `String` "derefs" to the simpler `str`, `Vec<T>` derefs to the simpler `[T]`.

Writing `*s` is just manually invoking [`Deref::deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#tymethod.deref) to turn `s` into its "simpler form".  It is almost always written `&*s`, however: although the `Deref::deref` signature says it returns a borrowed pointer (`&Target`), the compiler inserts a second automatic deref.  This is so that, for example, `{ let x = Box::new(42i32); *x }` results in an `i32` rather than a `&i32`.

So `&*s` is really just shorthand for `Deref::deref(&s)`.

`s[..]` is syntactic sugar for `s.index(RangeFull)`, implemented by the [`Index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait.  This means to slice the "whole range" of the thing being indexed; for both `String` and `Vec`, this gives you a slice of the entire contents.  Again, the result is *technically* a borrowed pointer, but Rust auto-derefs this one *as well*, so it's also almost always written `&s[..]`.

So what's the difference?  Hold that thought; let's talk about `Deref` chaining.

To take a specific example, because you can view a `String` as a `str`, it would be *really* helpful to have all the methods available on `str`s automatically available on `String`s as well.  Rather than inheritance, Rust does this by `Deref` chaining.

The way it works is that when you ask for a particular method on a value, Rust first looks at the methods defined for that specific type.  Let's say it doesn't find the method you asked for; before giving up, Rust will check for a `Deref` implementation.  If it finds one, it invokes it and then *tries again*.

This means that when you call `s.chars()` where `s` is a `String`, what's *actually* happening is that you're calling `s.deref().chars()`, because `String` doesn't *have* a method called `chars`, but [`str` *does*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars) (scroll up to see that `String` only gets this method because it implements `Deref<Target=str>`).

Getting back to the original question, the difference between `&*s` and `&s[..]` is in what happens when `s` is not *just* `String` or `Vec<T>`.  Let's take a few examples:

- `s: String`; `&*s: &str`, `&s[..]: &str`.
- `s: &String`: `&*s: &String`, `&s[..]: &str`.
- `s: Box<String>`: `&*s: &String`, `&s[..]: &str`.
- `s: Box<Rc<&String>>`: `&*s: &Rc<&String>`, `&s[..]: &str`.

`&*s` only *ever* peels away *one* layer of indirection.  `&s[..]` peels away *all of them*.  This is because none of `Box`, `Rc`, `&`, *etc.* implement the `Index` trait, so `Deref` chaining causes the call to `s.index(RangeFull)` to chain through all those intermediate layers.

Which one should you use?  Whichever you want.  Use `&*s` (or `&**s`, or `&***s`) if you want to control *exactly* how many layers of indirection you want to strip off.  Use `&s[..]` if you want to strip them all off and just get at the innermost representation of the value.

Or, you can do what I do and use `&*s` because it reads left-to-right, whereas `&s[..]` reads left-to-right-to-left-again and that annoys me.  :)

### Addendum

- There's the related concept of [`Deref` coercions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html).
- There's also [`DerefMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) and [`IndexMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) which do all of the above, but for `&mut` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 6):

They are completely the same for `String` and `Vec`.

The `[..]` syntax results in a call to `Index<RangeFull>::index()` and it's not just sugar for `[0..collection.len()]`. The latter would introduce the cost of bound checking. Gladly this is not the case in Rust so they both are equally fast.

---

Relevant code:

- [`index` of `String`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcollections/string.rs#L972-L980)
- [`deref` of `String`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcollections/string.rs#L1011-L1019)
- [`index` of `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1082-L1090) (just returns `self` which triggers the deref coercion thus executes exactly the same code as just `deref`)
- [`deref` of `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.4.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L1125-L1136)