# How to match against a &'static str in Rust

Tags: rust

I am a Rust beginner and I can't solve this type problem. I have tried replacing `&name` with `name`, but the error "pattern `&_` not covered"  occurred.

```
fn get_project(name: &'static str) {
    match &name {
        "hi" => {},
    }
}

fn main() {
    let project = get_project("hi");
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> <anon>:3:9
  |
3 |         "hi" => {},
  |         ^^^^ expected &str, found str
  |
  = note: expected type `&&str`
  = note:    found type `&'static str`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383488/how-to-match-a-string-against-string-literals-in-rust

Comment: I have seen,but can't solve my problem

Answer (score 6):

String literals – like `"hi"` – have the type `&'static str`. So if you already have a `&str`, you don't need to add the `&`:

```
fn get_project(name: &str) {
    match name {
        "hi" => {},
        _ => {}, // matches have to be exhaustive 
    }
}
```

I also added a *default case*, because matches in Rust need to be exhaustive: they need to cover all possible cases.

---

Maybe you noticed, that I also removed the `'static` from the argument list. If you want to read about some lifetime stuff, go ahead. Else, stop reading here, because it's possibly confusing and not that important in this case.

In this function there is no need to restrict the lifetime of the given argument to `'static`. Maybe you also want to pass in string slices that are borrowed from a `String`:

```
let user_input = read_user_input();  // type `String`
get_project(&input);
```

The code above only works when you remove the `'static` from the argument. Once removed, the function is equivalent to:

```
fn get_project<'a>(name: &'a str) { ... }
```

This means that the function is generic over a lifetime `'a`. The function says: given any lifetime `'a`, you can give me a string with said lifetime and I am able to do my thing. Which is true. If the function wouldn't be able to do it for any lifetime, the compiler would complain ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `name` doesn't need to have a `static` lifetime. Because you only use `name` inside your function, `name` doesn't need to have an extended lifetime. Check out the [strings chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.14.0/book/strings.html) of *The Rust Programming Language*. To match a `&str` with a `&'static str` you don't need `&`, just the variable itself is enough.

```
pub fn get_project(name: &str) {
    match name {
        "hi" => println!("I found hi!"),
        _ => println!("Nothing match"),
    }
}

fn main() {
    get_project("hi");
    get_project("42");
}
```

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Thanks, I'm new in rust. Your answer was very clear. I fix like I could.

Comment: @Stargateur I already saw your fix, my comment is gone ;-) And welcome to Rust, I hope you enjoy your stay ^_^