# Why can I compare a String to a &str using if, but not when using match?

Tags: string, rust, match, literals

I'm trying to implement a function that reads command line arguments and compares them to hard-coded string literals.

When I do the comparison with an `if` statement it works like a charm:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("holla!");

    if s == "holla!" {
        println!("it worked!");
    }
}
```

But using a `match` statement (which I guess would be more elegant):

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("holla!");

    match s {
        "holla!" => println!("it worked!"),
        _ => println!("nothing"),
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error from the compiler that a `String` was expected but a `&static str` was found:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |         "holla!" => println!("it worked!"),
  |         ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

I've seen [How to match a String against string literals in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25383488/155423) so I know how to fix it, but I want to know *why* the comparison works when `if` but not using `match`.

Comment: Because a `&str` is a reference, not a value.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. The question you have linked is very similar to mine, but I like to know why it works with the `if` comparison but not with a `match`.

Comment: It is simply because the compiler handles them both differently. The `if` statement delegates to the `PartialEq` implementation. The `match` doesn't have this special handling in the compiler and therefore requires a bit of help. The two constructs are compiled differently anyway so I'm not sure how this would work for the internals of the compiler. The `if` conditional becomes a simple branch whereas the `match` does appear (according to the LLVM IR) to be somewhat of a `switch` when compiled down.

Comment: If there are just two possible outcomes (like in your second example), an `if else` is a perfectly fine construct to use.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> I want to know why the comparison works when `if` but not using `match`.

It's not so much about `if` and more because you've used `==` in the condition. The condition in an `if` statement is any expression of type `bool`; you just happen to have chosen to use `==` there.

The `==` operator is really a function associated with [the `PartialEq` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html). This trait can be implemented for any *pair* of types. And, for convenience, `String` has implementations for `PartialEq<str>` and `PartialEq<&str>`, among others - and vice versa.

On the other hand, `match` expressions use [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.2.0/book/patterns.html) for comparison, not `==`. A `&'static str` literal, like `"holla!"`, is a valid pattern, but it can never match a `String`, which is a completely different type.

Pattern matching lets you concisely compare parts of complex structures, even if the whole thing isn't equal, as well as bind variables to pieces of the match. While `String`s don't really benefit from that, it's very powerful for other types, and has an entirely different purpose than `==`.

Note that you can use pattern matching with `if` by instead using the `if let` construct. Your example would look like this:

```
if let "holla!" = &*s {
    println!("it worked!");
}
```

Conversely, one way to use `==` inside a `match` is like this:

```
match s {
    _ if s == "holla!" => println!("it worked!"),
    _ => println!("nothing"),
}
```

Or, as @ljedrz suggested:

```
match s == "holla!" {
    true => println!("it worked!"), 
    _ => println!("nothing")
}
```

Answer (score 19):

## New answer

There's a marvelous method `String::as_str()` that allows to do exactly that:

```rust
match s.as_str() {
    "holla!" => println!("it worked!"),
    "Hallo!" => println!("with easy to read matches !"),
    _ => println!("nothing"),
}
```

---

## Old answer

As @peter-hall said, there's a mismatch of types because `match` expressions use pattern matching, which is different from the `==` that are associated with the `PartialEq` trait.

There a second way to resolve this issue, by casting your `String` into an `&str` (a string slice) :

```
match &s[..] {
    "holla!" => println!("it worked!"),
    "Hallo!" => println!("with easy to read matches !"),
    _ => println!("nothing"),
}
```

Comment: top answer! As match is special and String is special, we wish the compiler would do that for us.

Comment: @SamLiddicott The problem is that the core language doesn't define String, so making a special case for it is not ideal. So that would mean having a general way to do this. It could be through a trait that is used whenever there's a match, I'm just not sure of the implications of doing this.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to update this answer to use `.as_str()` instead so that ownership is preserved?

Comment: @CarloArenas ownership preserved? `&s[..]` doesn't take the ownership afaik. That being said, `.as_str()` is definitely the idiomatic way, so yeah I'll update. Thanks!