# How to match with vector element in Rust?

Tags: rust, match

In Rust, matching a value like this works:

```
let x = 1;

match x {
    1 => println!("one"),
    2 => println!("two"),
    _ => println!("something else")
}
```

But using values from a vector instead of hard-coded numbers in `match` doesn't work:

```
let x = 1;
let list = vec![1, 2];

match x {
    list[0] => println!("one"),
    list[1] => println!("two"),
    _ => println!("something else")
}
```

This fails with the message:

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `[`
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     list[0] => println!("one"),
  |         ^ expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|` here
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: See also: [Why can I compare a String to a &str using if, but not when using match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886160/why-can-i-compare-a-string-to-a-str-using-if-but-not-when-using-match/49889545#49889545)

Comment: That not the purpose of matching.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The pattern of a match arm is [defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html) as

```
Syntax
Pattern :
     LiteralPattern
   | IdentifierPattern
   | WildcardPattern
   | RangePattern
   | ReferencePattern
   | StructPattern
   | TupleStructPattern
   | TuplePattern
   | GroupedPattern
   | SlicePattern
   | PathPattern
   | MacroInvocation
```

It's either constant (including literal) or structural, not computed. A value defined as `list[0]` matches none of those definitions.

Fortunately, a match arm may also contain a [guard expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/book/patterns.html#guards), which allows for this:

```rust
let x = 1;
let list = vec![1, 2];

match x {
    _ if x == list[0] => println!("one"),
    _ if x == list[1] => println!("two"),
    _ => println!("something else")
}
```

Using `if else` would be cleaner, though (or a different structure if you have more cases, like a map, or the index).

Comment: Going to the grammar is nice, however I think we could go slightly higher level: a pattern is first and foremost **structural**. Apart from the exception of literal patterns, a pattern never matches a *value*, it matches a *shape*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. the "exception of literal patterns" is why it would make some kind of sense, though. This being said, I'm not against a more high level explanation.

Comment: I wonder whether `match ()` would be cleaner than `match x`. It would make obvious the `match` here is just hiding a if/else bag

Comment: The big question, though, is what use a `match` then? An `if/else` cascade would work as well. Unrelated: you should not need parenthesis around the condition of `if`.

Comment: @MatthieuM Literals are not the only values that can occur in patterns. Constants are allowed as well, and so are dataless enum variants.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: A dataless enum variant is just a special case of pattern-matching on an enum, though. Good point about constants, with the advent of const fns, this means non-builtin values.