# Match a slice of str or String

Tags: string, rust, match

I have a function that can take a `&[&str]` or a `&[String]` and return different values based on the slice. It works fine using `==` if I add a `PartialEq` constraint:

```rust
pub fn info1<'a, S>(path: &[S]) -> Option<String>
where
  S: PartialEq<&'a str>,
{
  if path == ["a", "b"] {
    return Some("It's a-b!".to_string())
  }
  None
}
```

But it doesn't work if I use `match`:

```rust
pub fn info2<'a, S>(path: &[S]) -> Option<String>
where
  S:  PartialEq<&'a str>,
{
  match path {
    ["a", "b"] => Some("It's a b!".to_string()),
    _ => None,
  }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:16:6
   |
11 | pub fn info2<'a, S>(path: &[S]) -> Option<String>
   |                  - this type parameter
...
15 |   match path {
   |         ---- this expression has type `&[S]`
16 |     ["a", "b"] => Some("It's a b!".to_string()),
   |      ^^^ expected type parameter `S`, found `&str`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `S`
                   found reference `&'static str`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8811ea10f1b20853ff5df898005b138b)

Is there any way to make it work? Ideally without requiring something like `["a".as_foo(), "b".as_foo()]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a helpful answer [from the Rust Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/match-a-slice-of-str-or-string/60055/2). It isn't possible to use `match` because patterns in `match` can only consist of `struct`s, `enum`s, `slice`s and literals. The best description of that I found is [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/match-a-slice-of-str-or-string/60055/2):

> A pattern consists of some combination of the following:
>
> - Literals
> - Destructured arrays, enums, structs, or tuples
> - Variables
> - Wildcards
> - Placeholders

In this case, a string literal like `"a"` is a `&str`, so that's really the only kind of string you can `match` against (and you can see people having basically the same problem but without the slice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383488/how-to-match-a-string-against-string-literals)). In that case you can work around it without allocation because you don't need to construct a slice of references - you only need one.

Since you definitely need a slice of `&str`s there's really no other way than to allocate a `Vec<&str>` [as suggested by Skysch](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/match-a-slice-of-str-or-string/60055/2):

```rust
pub fn info1<'a, S>(path: &[S]) -> Option<String>
where
  S: AsRef<str>,
{
  match &path.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref()).collect::<Vec<_>>()[..] {
    ["a", "b"] => Some("It's a b!".to_string()),
    _ => None,
  }
}
```

I think even with `macro_rules!` you couldn't solve it using `match`. However would be possible to make a `match`-like macro that uses `==` instead.

Comment: we may be "antagonistic" but I least we known that "Since you definitely need a slice of &strs there's really no other way than to allocate a Vec<&str>" is a bad solution

Comment: Allocating a `Vec` is a perfectly fine solution in 99% of cases. Not every bit of code has to be optimised to the nth degree.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `match` for this.

There is nothing wrong in your first version. You can make it more general using a [higher-ranked trait bound (`for<'a>`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/trait-bounds.html?highlight=for%3C%27a%3E#higher-ranked-trait-bounds):

```rust
pub fn info1<S>(path: &[S]) -> Option<String>
where
    for<'a> S: PartialEq<&'a str>,
{
    if path == ["a", "b"] {
        Some("It's a-b!".to_string());
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```