# Convert String to Vec<char> at compile time for pattern matching

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm writing a parser in Rust and I'm creating tokens from a `Vec<char>`. Currently, my code looks like

```rust
match &source[..] {
    ['l', 'e', 't', ..] => ...,
    ['t', 'r', 'u', 'e', ..] => ...,
    _ => ...
}
```

Obviously this is a lot more verbose than I'd like, and not easy to read. Is there any way I can convert `"let"` to `['l', 'e', 't']` at compile time (with a macro or const function) in order to pattern match on it like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match a String against string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383488/how-to-match-a-string-against-string-literals)

Comment: @EliasHolzmann No, because I’m matching against only the start of a char vec, and the patterns are of variable size.

Comment: Damn, you're right. Skimmed the title too quickly, sorry.

Comment: The obvious solution seems to be to use `&str` as your token type, or maybe `String` if you want to avoid dealing with the reference lifetimes and don't mind the allocations.

Comment: or use a parsing crate like nom

Comment: Your problem is obviously caused by `Vec<char>`. `char` is a completely useless type, there's no use-case for it. In particular, it doesn't represent any character. As for `Vec<char>`, it's just a memory inefficient `String`. For a parser, `Vec<u8>` would be much more useful, and then you can use byte literals. Or just use `String` with string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that with the macros from the Rust standard library, but you could write your own macro:

```rust
use proc_macro::{TokenStream, TokenTree, Group, Delimiter, Punct, Literal, Spacing};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, LitStr};

#[proc_macro]
pub fn charize(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // some stuff for later
    let comma_token = TokenTree::Punct(Punct::new(',', Spacing::Alone));
    let rest_token_iterator = std::iter::once(TokenTree::Punct(Punct::new('.', Spacing::Joint))).chain(std::iter::once(TokenTree::Punct(Punct::new('.', Spacing::Alone))));
    
    
    let string_to_charize: String = parse_macro_input!(input as LitStr).value();
    
    let char_tokens_iterator = string_to_charize.chars().map(|char| TokenTree::Literal(Literal::character(char)));
    // if you are on nightly, Iterator::intersperse() is much cleaner than this (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse)
    let char_tokens_interspersed_iterator = char_tokens_iterator.map(|token| [comma_token.clone(), token]).flatten().skip(1);
    let char_tokens_interspersed_with_rest_iterator = char_tokens_interspersed_iterator.chain(std::iter::once(comma_token.clone())).chain(rest_token_iterator);
    
    std::iter::once(TokenTree::Group(Group::new(Delimiter::Bracket, char_tokens_interspersed_with_rest_iterator.collect()))).collect()
    
}
```

Macro in action:

```rust
match &['d', 'e', 'm', 'o', 'n', 's', 't', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n'][..] {
    charize!("doesn't match") => println!("Does not match"),
    charize!("demo") => println!("It works"),
    charize!("also doesn't match") => println!("Does not match"),
    _ => panic!("Does not match")
}
```

Note that this is a procedural macro and as such must live in a [`proc_macro` crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#the-proc-macro-field).