# How to match against a String in a nested pattern

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I want to check whether a particular nested field is equal to a certain `String` and only run the arm if it is. Something like the following:

```rust
struct Bar {
    baz: usize,
    value: Option<String>
}

struct Foo {
    bar: Bar
}

let value = Foo { bar: Bar { baz: 1, value: Some("foobar".to_string()) } };

match value {
    Foo {
        bar: Bar {
            baz,
            value: Some("foobar") // does not work since &str != String
        }
    } => println!("Matched! baz: {}", baz),
    _ => panic!("No Match")
}
```

Adding a match guard works but constant `String`s aren't a thing so I can't guard using that, the only possibility I see is to guard against a new `String` like so:

```rust
struct Bar {
    value: Option<String>
}

struct Foo {
    bar: Bar
}

let value = Foo { bar: Bar { value: Some("foobar".to_string()) } };

match value {
    Foo {
        bar: Bar { baz, value },
    } if value == Some("foobar".to_string()) => println!("Matched! baz: {}", baz),
    _ => panic!("No Match"),
}
```

Is this my only option or is there a better way?

Note: I have seen [How to match a String against string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383488/how-to-match-a-string-against-string-literals) but my match is nested and more complicated (the above is only an example) so I can't just match against a reference to the `String`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, there is a feature that is WIP in the compiler that will allow you to match the nested string with a literal `&str`. This is part of a bigger project to allow nested matching over values that are obtained by dereferencing the matched value (this would be possible in your case because `String: Deref<Target=str>`). This is partly possible right now, but they [the Rust lang team] are waiting to have a fully general solution before making it available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the value inside the `Some`, which would give you a value of type `String`, which you can then compare with `==` in an `if` guard:

```rust
    match value {
        Foo {
            bar: Bar {
                baz,
                value: Some(value),
            },
        } if value == "foobar" => println!("Matched! baz: {}", baz),
        _ => panic!("No Match"),
    }
```

Output:

```
Matched! baz: 1
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=628fe81165d22ca8225f44b128c9573a)

As @drewtato pointed out in a comment below, this will `move` the whole `value`. If you want to reuse `value` again, you can match with `Some(ref value)` and the comparison will still work.